# Monero CLI show_transfers coming in that are less than X amount

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, cli, show-transfers

Is there a way to see incoming amounts that are less or greater than an amount? When doing `show_transfers in` it shows everything. How can I filter this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of *many* possible ways:

```
monero-wallet-cli --wallet-file yourwallet --password 'yourpass' show_transfers in \
    | sed 1,11d | perl -ane 'print if $F[5] < 10'
```

Prints all incoming transfers less than 10 XMR.

You can omit the `sed 1,11d` if you also want the header lines.